# Flot chart won't re-draw

Tags: jquery, ajax, flot

I'm getting one set of data when the page is initially loaded, and displaying it in a flot chart.  I have a drop down menu that allows the user to select "year to date" or "month to date", and everything is working fine, except the chart doesn't redraw the chart, so when you change the selection to "month to date", it still lists all calendar months on the x axis instead of the days of the month.  I've tried using `$.plot.setupGrid()` and `$.plot.draw()`, also `chartTaggedSpending.setupGrid()` and `chartTaggedSpending.draw()`, and it isn't working, so I'm doing something wrong here.  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Here's the code called in the `ajax.done()` function block:

```
if(selectView = 1 && response.length != 0) {

        var chartTaggedSpending = $('#tagged-spending');
        var arrMonthLabels = [[1, 'Jan'], [2, 'Feb'], [3, 'Mar'],[4, 'Apr'],
[5, 'May'],[6, 'Jun'], [7, 'Jul'], [8, 'Aug'], [9, 'Sep'], [10, 'Oct'],
[11, 'Nov'], [12, 'Dec']];
        $.plot(chartTaggedSpending,
            [
                {
                    data: response[1].data,
                    label: 'Budgeted: ' + response[1].label,
                    lines: { show: true},
                    points: { show: true, radius: 7 }
                },
                {
                    data: response[0].data,
                    label: 'Spent: ' + response[0].label,
                    lines: { show: true}, 
                    points: { show: true, radius: 7 }
                }
            ],
            {
                colors: ['#a6db34', '#33a6db'],   
                legend: { show: true },
                grid: { borderWidth: 0, hoverable: true, clickable: true },
                yaxis: {min: 0, max: 2000, ticks: 10, tickColor: '#eeeeee' },
                xaxis: { 
                    min: 1,
                    max: 12,
                    ticks: arrMonthLabels,
                    tickColor: '#ffffff' 
                }
            }
        );
    }
    if(selectView = 0 && response.length != 0) {
        var chartTaggedSpending = $('#tagged-spending');
        $.plot(chartTaggedSpending,
            [
                {
                    data: response[1].data,
                    label: 'Budgeted: ' + response[1].label,
                    lines: { show: true},  
                    points: { show: true, radius: 7 },
                },
                {
                    data: response[0].data,
                    label: 'Spent: ' + response[0].label,
                    lines: { show: true}, 
                    points: { show: true, radius: 7 }
                }
            ],
            {
                colors: ['#a6db34', '#33a6db'],   
                legend: { show: true },
                grid: { borderWidth: 0, hoverable: true, clickable: true },
                yaxis: {min: 0, max: 1500, ticks: 10, tickColor: '#eeeeee' },
                xaxis: { 
                    min: 1,
                    max: 31,
                    ticks: 31,
                    tickColor: '#ffffff' 
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: can you tell me the solution of your problem. Actually I also have same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.setupGrid` and `.draw` are methods of a plot object.  This plot object **is returned** from a `.plot` call.

```
var chartTaggedSpending = $('#tagged-spending');
var myPlot = $.plot(chartTaggedSpending, etc.... // assign the return from $.plot
// sometime later
myPlot.setupGrid(); // use it later
myPlot.draw();
```

Comment: I attempted to structure my code above like you have demonstrated here, but I must be missing something, because it still doesn't work.  when I change the select option to the other chart, the data changes, so I know everything is working up until that point, but it just isn't redrawing the chart, no matter how I try it.

Comment: @hyphen, Can you create a jsFiddle reproducing your problems?